# launching vs2008 build from python

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio-2008, build-automation

The first batch file launches a command prompt, i need the second command to be in the ccontext of the first.  how can I do this in python?

As is, it launches the batch, and blocks until the batch (with its command prompt context) terminates, and then executes `devenv` without the necessary context.

```
os.system(r'%comspec% /k ""C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"" x86')
os.system(r'devenv asdf.sln /rebuild Debug /Out last-build.txt')
```

think of it as in i'm in bash, and i need to execute a command in a perl context, so i type `perl -c 'asdf'`.  executing perl and asdf back to back won't work, i need to get the `devenv` inside of the perl context.

Comment: Is there a reason you are not launching msbuild instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I these situations I use script that does it all. That way you can chain as much as you want. Sometimes I will generate the script on the fly.

```
compileit.cmd
  call C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat
  devenv $1.sln /rebuild Debug /Out last-build.txt
```

Comment: 2nd vote for generating the script then running it.  Cat the command lines into a file and then call it, then delete the file.  Saves you another build artifact that has to be maintained outside your primary build script (ant, for us).

Comment: FYI: devenv.exe will never get executed unless you use the "call" command to invoke vcvarsall.bat.

Comment: devenv is not the proper way to do command line builds. You should use vcbuild for vc <=9.0 and msbuild for versions >=10.0.

Answer (score 3):

I think that the proper way for achieving this would be running this command:

```
%comspec% /C "%VCINSTALLDIR%\vcvarsall.bat" x86 && vcbuild "project.sln"
```

Below you'll see the Python version of the same command:

```
os.system('%comspec% /C "%VCINSTALLDIR%\\vcvarsall.bat" x86 && vcbuild "project.sln"')
```

This should work with any Visual Studio so it would be a good idea to edit the question to make it more generic.

There is a small problem I found regarding the location of vcvarsall.bat - Because VCINSTALLDIR is not always set, you have to use the registry entries in order to detect the location where it is installer:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0]
"InstallDir"="c:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\\Common7\\IDE\\"
```

Add `..\..\VC\vcvarsall.bat` to this path. Also is a good idea to test for other versions of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2):

You could append the devenv command onto the end of the original batch file like so:

```
'%comspec% /k "...vcvarsall.bat" x86 && devenv asdf.sln /rebuild ...'
```

(obviously I have shortened the commands for simplicity's sake)

Answer (score 2):

I run my Python script from a batch file that sets the variables :-)

```
call ...\vcvarsall.bat
c:\python26\python.exe myscript.py
```

But Brett's solution sounds better.